# Translating English to First order Logic question

Tags: first-order-logic, predicate-logic, logic-translation

Please help me convert the statements 1,2 and 3 into First Order Logic formulas given the following predicates.

Note: You can also use new predicates.

f(X) = "X is a fruit",

a(X)= "X is an apricot",

p(X) = "X is an pineapple",

b(X) = "X is bad",

k(X,Y) = "X is more knowledgeable than Y"

w(X) = "X is a woman."

s(X)= X is spoilt

(1) apricots and pineapples are bad fruits and spoilt.

My attempt: a(X) ∧ p(X) -> b(X) ∧ f(X) ∧ s(X)

(2) Every fruit other than apricots and pineapples is bad and spoilt.

My attempt: ∀X f(X) ∧ (¬ (a(X) ∧ p(X))) -> b(X) ∧ s(X)

(3) Some women are more knowledgeable than others except than herself.

My attempt: ∃X w(X) -> k(X)

Comment: Please format the formulas and use parentheses.

Comment: For (1), first I think there's a typo and that you mean $p$ rather than $o$. Second note that $X$ can't be both an apricot and a pineapple, but it can be one OR the other.

Comment: Your first is wrong.  What you have written translates back to words as: "If X is both an apricot and a pineapple, then it is a fruit, bad, and spoilt," X **cannot** be both an apricot and a pineapple.  You want "or" not "and". For (2) you again need "or" not "and".  For (3) there is no "k(X)" defined! only "k(X, Y)".

Comment: (3) is clearly wrong: $k$ is a binary predicate.

Comment: @user474330 yes it is p(X) sorry for that.

Comment: @user247327  yes I too thought the same,.. so should it be (1) a(X) V p(X) -> b(X) ∧ f(X) ∧ s(X) ? and for (2) is it ∀X f(X) ∧ (¬ (a(X) V p(X))) -> b(X) ∧ s(X) ... is this correct??

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA, yes.. I am new to all this.. don't know exactly how to solve this.

Comment: Hint: You are comparing one woman to another

Comment: @AnotherJohnDoe, ok so I am just guessing this ∃X ∀Y w(X)  -> (k(X,Y) ∧ ¬ w(X))  ????

Comment: $(1)$Is there also a condition on $Y$? $(2)$Your statement reads as $there\ exists$ women, such that $for\ all\ Y\ (Y\ what?)$, $X$ is more knowledgeable than $Y$, and $X$ is not a woman. Do you see the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(1) apricots and pineapples are bad fruits and spoilt.

My attempt: $(a(X) \lor o(X)) \implies (b(X) ∧ f(X) ∧ s(X))$

(2) Every fruit other than apricots and pineapples is bad and spoilt.

My attempt: $∀X (f(X) ∧ (¬ (a(X) \lor o(X)))) \implies (b(X) ∧ s(X))$

(3) Some women are more knowledgeable than others except than herself.

My attempt: $∃X\forall Y (w(X)\land w(Y)\land X\ne Y) \implies k(X,Y)$

EDIT my 2nd attempt for (3):

$(∃X\forall Y) w(X)\land((w(Y)\land X\ne Y) \implies k(X,Y))$

Comment: Thank you very much @djura you saved my day!

Comment: @marinkov,  Sorry for asking late but can you pls explain me what logic you used to solve the 3rd part? I dont understand why you have mentioned X≠Y in the formula

Comment: @confucious well, she can't be more knowledgeable than herself, that's why you exclude case X=Y

Comment: Can we write the logic like this also?? ∃X∀Y(w(X)∧w(Y))⟹k(X,Y)∧¬k(X,X)

Comment: @confucious no, what you wrote is definitely not ok. but neither mine is. I will edit it in a minute

Comment: Ok that's what I was thinking too. There was some glitch in the formula.  Thank you for your correction

Comment: So how does the new formula differ from the old one. I don't see the difference somehow :(

Comment: Does this example help? "There is a student who is loved by every other student."
∃ x ( Student(x) ∧ ∀ y ( Student(y) ∧ ¬(x = y) ⇒ Loves(y,x) ))

Comment: @confucious Yes, that example is exact same as yours. Difference between my old and new formulas is that first formula is true whenever X is not a woman, which you don't want